# Detect Low Energy bluetooth device only on button press

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ibeacon

I am trying to build a app using low energy bluetooth beacons, for android whenever a beacon comes near my phone it gets detected without pressing button

what I want is it should be detected only when beacon button is pressed

code I am using is

```
 private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }
}

private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
        Log.i("result", result.toString());
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
        connectToDevice(btDevice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        for (ScanResult sr : results) {
            Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                 byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                        connectToDevice(device);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {

}
```

Do I need to implement any gatt callbacks or is there any method so I get notified when button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                cancelButton.setText(R.string.scan);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        cancelButton.setText(R.string.cancel);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        cancelButton.setText(R.string.scan);
    }

}
```

Comment: already tried it, disabling bluetooth what effect does it make?

Comment: Add in your callback : if(mScanning) { connectToDevice(device); } .Just check it work or not.

Comment: no luck, still being detected without button press
previously I was using mgatt.connect in connecttodevice, can it be due to that do I have to disconnect it or something on application reinstall?

Comment: Not sure about mgatt disconnect but try it. and use any background service for scanning?